# db gallery: one image in multiple albums or one image in one album

Tags: mysql, database, image

I'm on the process of creating an image gallery. The model i'm planning to build is very simple: I have categories that have albums with images that are tagged.

When it comes to allowing one image to be in more then 1 album, im not sure what is the standard out there or how the best galleries software are doing it...

Is the standard to allow the same image in multiple albums? or the image goes in only one album and i should use tags?

Anyone has an idea or can guide me.. this is an important part of the core model and i want it to be perfect from the start.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[DBGallery](http://dbgallery.com) allows images to be stored in folders and has 'virtual sets'.  So rather than duplicating images an image in a Virtual Set simply points back to the image in a folder.  An image can belong to any number of Virtual Sets.  If the source image is updated using photoshop or it's data tags are edited it is reflected in all Virtual Sets.  There is a video on YouTube introducing them here (although they're called Handy Collections in the video...same thing).  So the vote here is to do an hybrid.  This is also what is recommended in the excellent ["The DAM Book"](http://www.thedambook.com/), a book on DAM software which has been widely read since approx 2006.